# Convert one-dimensional array to two-dimensional array so that each element is a row in the result

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I want to know how to convert this: `array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` to this:

```py
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5]])
```

In short, given a flat array, repeat each element inside the array n times, so that each element creates a sub-array of n of the same element, and concatenate these sub-arrays into one, so that each row contains an element from the original array repeated n times.

I can do this:

```py
def repeat(lst, n):
    return [[e]*n for e in lst]
```

```
>repeat(range(10), 4)

[[0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [3, 3, 3, 3],
 [4, 4, 4, 4],
 [5, 5, 5, 5],
 [6, 6, 6, 6],
 [7, 7, 7, 7],
 [8, 8, 8, 8],
 [9, 9, 9, 9]]
```

How to do this in NumPy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy's [`repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) like this:

```
np.repeat(range(10), 4).reshape(10,4)
```

which gives:

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1]
 [2 2 2 2]
 [3 3 3 3]
 [4 4 4 4]
 [5 5 5 5]
 [6 6 6 6]
 [7 7 7 7]
 [8 8 8 8]
 [9 9 9 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) that handles dimensions:

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
N = 4

np.tile(a[:,None], (1, N))

# or
np.tile(a, (N, 1)).T
```

or [`broadcast_to`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html):

```
np.broadcast_to(a, (N, a.shape[0])).T

# or
np.broadcast_to(a[:,None], (a.shape[0], N))
```

Or multiply by an array of ones:

```
a[:,None]*np.ones(N, dtype=a.dtype)
```

output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5, 5]])
```